# Synchronise Database between servers via php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm needing to synchronise two mysql databases between different servers on a regular basis, by a client-initiated interface. I've been doing it by remote MYSQL connection, and adding the IP of the servers to the whitelist for MYSQL remote connections. Problem is however, that the client has a dynamic IP, so as soon as it changes they can no longer sync.

So I'm trying to find an alternative way of synchronising the two databases via some sort of secure php script.

**edit**: I should make this a bit clearer. I've got a server (WAMP) running on a PC (Win7) the database of which I need to synchronize (both ways) to an online server. I've been doing it via remote MySQL connect, which I'd like to avoid because of dynamic IPs, and also because the local WAMP server connects to different internet connections (being a laptop) and needs to not be restricted to one IP.

Comment: Have you considered [database replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-howto.html)? You can tunnel it [over SSH](http://www.networkcomputing.com/servers-storage/how-to-set-up-ssh-encrypted-mysql-replication.php) or IPSec.

Comment: Lèse majesté suggestion would be by far the best approach you could take.

Comment: @Lèsemajesté & @JohnCartwrite : This would be okay if I only wanted changes on the master to be replicated on the slave, but I actually need to synchronise both ways. New changes on db1 to be replicated on db2, and new changes on db2 to be replicated on db1. Is this possible with database replication? Is this possible to do in MYSQL alone? I've written a PHP script to do this, but I just need to be able to securely pass data between remote servers.

Comment: It's quite difficult to image why you would set this up this way. It would make it nearly impossible, or in several magnitudes difficulty, to create a properly normalized and relational database. Replication is only for a master -> slave relationship. If you need 2 way syncronization, I would just keep your current setup, and use a service such as http://www.no-ip.com/ to have your client maintain a static hostname on a dynamic IP address.

Comment: @Emmanuel: Yes, it is possible to set up two-way replication, but you'd need to take care of the problem of atomicity of cross-server updates yourself. So it may be better to just do as John Cartwright suggests. Should you still want to try two-way replication, here is a good guide: http://onlamp.com/pub/a/onlamp/2006/04/20/advanced-mysql-replication.html

Comment: @Lèsemajesté & @JohnCartwrite : If I could setup two-way replication that would be great... However I've got an unusual setup. I should have made things clearer from the start. However, What I've got is a local PC (win7) running WAMP server, and I'm needing to synchronize the database on the PC with the online server. I don't think MySQL replication will work because there's no way I know of to get the online server to connect to the remote PC. What I've been doing is getting the WAMP server to connect to the online mysql host via a php script and then synchronizing via multiple mysql queries.

Comment: I guess I could just $_POST the data back and forth and work out a way of reading the data and inserting new values into the database, but doing it securely is my biggest concern. It is fairly sensitive data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

However you want to synchronize the databases (replication, a PHP script, etc.), the best way to secure it would be to either use an IPSec/VPN or SSH tunnel to encrypt all the communication between the two servers. Then you'd just open a regular mysql or http connection through the tunnel.

Using either method, you'll have access to a variety of authentication modes. So you could use a pre-shared key or username/password authentication or both.

You can use an SSH client like PuTTY to initiate an SSH tunnel on a Windows systems. Or if you google IPSec and XAuth, you should be able to find some guides on how to set up an authenticated IPSec VPN.

Comment: èsemajesté : Thanks so much for your help. I'm going to give this a go. Found a good tutorial: http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/make_ssh_connections_with_php/ 
 WAMP supports php_ssh2 and I've installed it on my online server. All set! Thanks so much for all your help.